# Strange Xcode error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

When I run my app, i get one error and i dont know how to fix it. Can someone help me?

Here is the error:

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Picture: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/200/screenshot20110609at256.png/

Thanks

Comment: Note that GCC failing with an exit code isn't an error; it's a report of an error.

Answer (score 1):

The causative problem is the error immediately preceding that one, the duplicate symbol error.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it seems like `didUpdate` is defined more than once in your code. Search for `didUpdate` on your workspace and make sure it's only being defined once.

Answer (score 1):

gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1 Error Occurs due to some of your file or frame work are duplicated check it out which file is in you target link file or in your framework are repeated.

from your log message "didUpdate" may be repeated in your project look for that...

May be this is helpful to You.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are redefining variable or you are probably importing a *.m file somewhere in your project.Try importing corresponding *.h file.